# Calling a function with ng directive from injected html via Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use a Chrome Extension as a complimentary tool for the web app I'm developing.

I used `chrome.tab.executeScript` to manipulate the DOM of the web app and append a button inside a `DIV`.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({

    code: 'var e =  document.createElement("div");' +
              'e.innerHTML = "' + 
              '<button ng-click="myfnc()"></button>' +
              '";' +    
              'document.getElementsByTagName("body").appendChild(e);'

});
```

The button is added/appended as expected.

```
<body>
    <div>
       <button ng-click="myfnc()"></button>
    </div>
</body>
```

The button has **ng-click** attribute that points to function on the web app. The function is just a simple alert call.

**myfnc():**

```
alert('Hello!');
```

However, when I click on the button nothing happens. Do you have any idea why? Can injected html coming from Google Chrome Extension interact directly with the web page's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an element with the attribute `ng-click` does not inform Angular that the element exists within the page, as parsing of the document occurs once during bootstrap. You therefore have an element which exists 'outside' of any Angular scope, meaning the attribute `ng-click` *just exists* and has not caused the corresponding directive (`ngClick`) to be invoked.

Providing of course that the page has Angular, you will want to use the [`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) along with the desired `$scope` to compile the element after it has been inserted into the page.

A comprehensive solution is outside of the scope of your question. (*Why does nothing happen when the button is clicked?*) If you want to read more about using injected code with Angular, read up on:

- the [`angular.element#scope()` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), which lets you pick up the `$scope` object of an element,
- appending an `angular.element` using the [`append()` method](https://api.jquery.com/append/) available on angular elements
- using the derived `$scope` object in [compiling elements](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) such that Angular is aware of it

The steps you want to take are something like...

1. Get the `$scope` you want to insert the element within:

   ```
   var angular = document.querySelector('body');
   var scope = angular.element(angular).scope();
   ```
2. Insert the new element into the page:

   ```
   var newElem = angular.element('div');
   angular.append(newElem);
   ```
3. `$compile` the element with this `$scope`:

   ```
   $compile(newElem)(scope);
   ```

More information on dynamically creating Angular elements can be found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025526/angularjs-dynamically-creating-elements-that-specify-directives).

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I'll try to learn more about this. 
In item 2 is it `angular.append(ngElem);` or `angular.append(newElem);`?

Comment: So what i have to do is get the `$scope` where I want to put the button;  append the element and use `$compile` to _render_ it on the page. That really makes sense. The only problem with this is `chrome.tabs.executeScript` does not have access to the `angularjs` file and other javascripts on the webpage. It runs on an _isolated world_, thus your suggestion will have this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` @sdgluck

Comment: @jimx Inject a `<script>` into the page that performs these actions, rather than attempt to do them within the background script. :-)

Comment: That came to mind! :D Yes that might actually work. I'll use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject a `<script>` on the page. The injected script will contain a function with steps you enumerated; call the function and hope it works.