# AngularJS access dynamically created html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, google-visualization

I am trying to access a function within a newly created DOM element but I cannot. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

```
$scope.createCustomHTMLContent = function(img, evtTime, cmname, evt, cust, serv, descr, duration) {

   var html =  '<div class="row"><div class="btn-default"><button ng- click="testFun()">Edit</button></div>' + '</div>';

  return html;

}


rows.push([""+cmname, ""+id,$scope.createCustomHTMLContent(thumbpath, evtTime, cmname, evt, cust, serv, descr, 0),new Date(datetime), new Date(datetime1),'color:'+colors[serv]]);
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

The code is alot, so I tried to include what is necessary only. Please let me know if you need any clarity.

Basically the button is displayed as a tooltip. but when I click it does not call the testFun function. Thank you

Comment: It is unclear with the amount of code you provided. Your pushing an array  with parameter.. one of which is "html" string. where are you compiling this html string?

Comment: Okay, the html is used to create a tooltip on a google chart timeline. But I cannot access my functions once it is clicked.

Comment: What I was is to be able to access my functions on click after creating the elements.

Comment: When you create HTML dynamically they should be compiled and a scope should be assigned for them. Only then, any methods or variables present on that html will know which scope do they belong to. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025526/angularjs-dynamically-creating-elements-that-specify-directives

Comment: I tried that, it still does not work. I think Its because google charts draws those tooltips and not me

Answer (score 0):

Google Charts *dynamically* generates DOM element for tooltip element, `$compile` service needs to be used in that case to bind the tooltip markup, the following example demonstrates how to use `ng-click` in tooltip:

```js
angular.module('ChartApp', [])

    .controller('ChartCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

        $scope.logItems = [];

        $scope.viewDetails = function (index) {
            $scope.logItems.push(index + ' row clicked');
        };

        $scope.initChart = function () {

            google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Year');
                dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
                // A column for custom tooltip content
                dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: { html: true } });
                dataTable.addRows([
                    ['2010', 600, '<div id="tooltip-inner-container"><h2>Details for 2010 year</h2> <br/><button ng-click="viewDetails(0)">View</button></div>'],
                    ['2011', 1500, '<div id="tooltip-inner-container"><h2>Details for 2011 year</h2> <br/><button ng-click="viewDetails(1)">View</button></div>'],
                    ['2012', 800, '<div id="tooltip-inner-container"><h2>Details for 2012 year</h2> <br/><button ng-click="viewDetails(2)">View</button></div>'],
                    ['2013', 1000, '<div id="tooltip-inner-container"><h2>Details for 2013 year</h2> <br/><button ng-click="viewDetails(3)">View</button></div>']
                ]);


              

                var options = {
                    tooltip: {
                        isHtml: true,
                        trigger: 'selection'
                    },
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(dataTable, options);

                //
                function initTooltip() {
                        var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip-inner-container");
                        if (tooltip != null){
                            var t = $compile(tooltip.outerHTML)($scope);
                            angular.element(tooltip).replaceWith(t);
                        }  
                }

                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', initTooltip);
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', initTooltip);
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', initTooltip);
            }

        };



        $scope.initChart();


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ChartApp" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
     <pre style="width: 30%; height: 10pc; overflow-y: scroll; float:left;">
       {{logItems | json}} 
    </pre>
    <div id="chart_div" style="float:left; width:60%; height: 180px;"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/jrvjpQ)